# How to check if the password entered by user is correct (in the command encrypted with OpenSSL)?

Tags: python, bash, shell, encryption, openssl

How to find out if the password entered by user is correct (in the command encrypted with OpenSSL)? I want to run another command if the password is successful.
Voila my code :

```
#!/bin/bash
#decryption operation
openssl aes-128-cbc -d -in config.py.aes128 -out config.py
#run another command if password is correct
./doSomething.py
```

Comment: I'm quite reluctant answering this, because the whole general concept, of what you're doing there is just capital B bad, from a security point of view. Yes, it's perfectly possible to gather if openssl did successfully decrypt the data. Something something "process termination status code". But to me it looks like, as if you attempt to protect credentials of some application, either before checking them into a repository or deployment, by encrypting the config file that holds then. Totally wrong approach. Learn how to use certificate based authentication.

Comment: You are right. But this question is for a small local issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With all respect for the @EchoMike44 suggestion, have you tried this?

```bash
#!/bin/bash
openssl aes-128-cbc -d -in config.py.aes128 -out config.py && \
  ./doSomething.py || \
    exit 1
```

If you don't need detailed messages in the output, so this will work with the same logic but in short syntax.

I mean if the ExitCode of the `openssl ...` command was 0 (successful) then will run `./doSomething.py` otherwise it will exit from the bash script with the ExitCode of `1`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you catch the exit code if openssl fail to decrypt the file .

**OPTION 1** : you can use `$?`

```
#!/bin/bash
# create a temporary file for output errors
ERR_OUTPUT=$(mktemp)
openssl aes-128-cbc -d  -in config.py.aes128 -out  config.py    >"${ERR_OUTPUT}" 2>&1
EXIT_CODE=$?
if [  ${EXIT_CODE} -ne 0 ]
then
    echo ERROR decryption failed
    cat "${ERR_OUTPUT}"
    rm -f "${ERR_OUTPUT}"
    exit ${EXIT_CODE}
fi
rm -f "${ERR_OUTPUT}"
./doSomething.py
```

**OPTION 2** : you can embed the execution of the command in the `if` clause

```
#!/bin/bash
# create a temporary file for output errors
ERR_OUTPUT=$(mktemp)
if ( ! openssl aes-128-cbc -d  -in config.py.aes128 -out  config.py  >"${ERR_OUTPUT}" 2>&1 )
then
    echo ERROR decryption failed
    cat "${ERR_OUTPUT}"
    rm -f "${ERR_OUTPUT}"
    exit 1
fi
rm -f "${ERR_OUTPUT}"
./doSomething.py
```

**OPTION 3** : you can use `||` between openssl and a block that will executed only if openssl generate a error

```
#!/bin/bash
# create a temporary file for output errors
ERR_OUTPUT=$(mktemp)
openssl aes-128-cbc -d  -in config.py.aes128 -out  config.py  >"${ERR_OUTPUT}" 2>&1 || (
    echo ERROR decryption failed
    cat "${ERR_OUTPUT}"
    rm -f "${ERR_OUTPUT}"
    exit ${EXIT_CODE}
)
rm -f "${ERR_OUTPUT}"
./doSomething.py
```